# How do I update GRUB in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, grub2

In Ubuntu, we use this command to update GRUB:

```
# update-grub
```

But how do I update GRUB version **2.00** in Arch Linux?

Comment: normally grub is upgraded via pacman when there is an update. You must run `pacman -Syu`

Comment: when grub is updated via pacman, automatically launch `grub-mkconfig` to properly configure the new grub version

Comment: You should uninstall `grub` - youre only complicating things using it at all.

Comment: Grub is the only thing I've ever used for dual boot setups. Care to offer a less complicated alternative @mikeserv? I've looked at syslinux but never could get it to do what I wanted. It was too complicated.

Comment: [Is GRUB the best bootloading solution? Is there an easier alternative?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146784/is-grub-the-best-bootloading-solution-is-there-an-easier-alternative/146803#146803) - if you go through with it, i'm willing to bet you'll be happier for it. [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212970/52934) walks-through an installation in detail, though the use-case is pretty targeted there. The best place to learn is at http://rodsbooks.com - but the first link will take you there.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The `update-grub` command is just a script which runs the `grub-mkconfig` tool to generate a grub.cfg file. See the Archlinux GRUB [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Generate_the_main_configuration_file). It refers to the following:

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Or `grub2-mkconfig` on some systems (e.g., Fedora 36)?

Comment: [A sample](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first/692898#692898).

Answer (score 2):

You can install the same update-grub command on arch linux with this aur package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/update-grub/

Answer (score 1):

One solution is for pacman to automatically update grub, which is accomplished by installing `grub-hook` from AUR.

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/grub-hook/

Answer (score 0):

There is also the graphical tool [grub-customizer](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/grub-customizer/) that automatically runs `os-prober` and lets you customize the GRUB prompt in many ways.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: IIRC it was more convenient to use than `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig` and solved the same problem for me back then.