# Problems with Grub and rEFIt in Fedora

Tags: fedora, macintosh, refit

I used to run my Macbook in triple boot - Ubuntu, Fedora and Osx.
When I turn the computer on, it goes to rEFIt menu and I could then choose between the OS's. 
Suddenly, it started to boot directly on Fedora's Grub menu. 
Now I can't boot in Osx or Ubuntu anymore.
What can I do?

Comment: What happens if you intercept the boot holding down the alt [option] key after POST?

Comment: I didn't undertand the "after POST" part, but it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Use rEFInd, not rEFIt. rEFIt's been defunct for a very long time. Else, you want to try another rEFIt fork, check out the clover bootloader - it's more Mac-centric anyway. And, if you like yourself, uninstall `grub` entirely.

Comment: @mikeserv :  I never liked rEFIt, but I like grub. I will try rEFInd and clover.
I am planing to install a triple boot with windows, osx and some linux distribution. Would you recomend some order in the instalation? I know that when you install windows in some partition you need to reconfigure the bootloader (at least grub). Maybe installing Windows first I could overcome this troubles...

Comment: [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212970/52934) is a step-by-step I did on configuring a linux machine's boot. It may be helpful to you. And [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146803/52934) is an answer which may explain how useless `grub` truly is to you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you intercept the boot holding down the alt [option] key after POST?

(POST = "Power-On Self Test; that is, the beep or, in a Mac's case, the "bong" sound that the computer makes after it has successfully powered on.)

Comment: Oh, I googled it and just found something related to http.
The alt key prompted me into the Startup Manager menu, where I could choose beetwen Fedora and rEFIt.