# How to scroll up the cursor in terminal in order to print a string?

Tags: bash, terminal

Here I want something like the way `aircrack-ng` does to display text in the terminal screen, or like matrix scripts ... !

For example, if my terminal screen already contains 4 lines, I want to update the 1st of those first lines in its place, and same for other lines ... (using bash)

To be more precise, I want a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
  do
    echo "line1"
    echo "line2"
    echo "line3"
    echo "line4"
    # without using clear cmd, next cycle line1 should be printed
    # in line1 place not in a new line , and same for other lines
  done
```

Comment: `man terminfo` will give you cursor movement operations, which can be implement via the `tput` command. For example `tput home`. The interesting ones include "remember my current (x,y) position" and "return to the remembered position". If I could remember what they were I'd write a full answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On terminals that support it, you can use `tput sc` to save the cursor position and `tput rc` to restore it:

```
i=0
tput sc
while sleep 1; do
  tput rc
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
done
```

[image: output]

You can save those escape sequences in a variable to avoid having to invoke `tput` every time:

```
rc=$(tput rc) ||
  echo >&2 "Warning: terminal doesn't support restoring the cursor"
...
printf '%s\n' "${rc}line1..."
```

On the rare terminals that don't support it, you can always use cursor positioning sequences,

```
while sleep 1; do
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
  echo "line$((i=i+1))"
  tput cuu 4 # or up=$(tput cuu1); printf %s "$up$up$up$up"
done
```

See the `terminfo` man page in section 5 (if your system ships with ncurses) for more details.

Comment: How do we find out which terminals support it (aside from actually running the code)?

Comment: @muru `infocmp -L1 "$terminal" | grep save_cursor` or `TERM=$terminal tput sc > /dev/null`. You can loop over the terminals in /usr/share/terminfo.

Comment: This does not work when the output scrolls the terminal; `tput sc` is absolute, not relative.

Answer (score 7):

I answered this on StackOverflow a few months ago, see *[Overwriting last terminal output(multiple lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198221/overwriting-last-terminal-outputmultiple-lines)*.  While I suppose it is *possible* that OP meant to print literally "line1", "line2", etc., that would only be of interest in a classroom exercise.  Real programs print more interesting things, so I am answering *that* question. As before, the current q/a overlooks the problem when updated lines are shorter than the existing line.  Addressing that

```
#!/bin/bash
tput sc
while :
  do
    tput rc
    echo "line1"; tput el
    echo "line2"; tput el
    echo "line3"; tput el
    echo "line4"; tput el
    # without using clear cmd, next cycle line1 should be printed
    # in line1 place not in a new line , and same for other lines
  done
```

Agreeing that `cuu` is a good alternative, using `grep` to check the availability of a capability seems less effective than using `tput` itself, e.g.,

```
restore=$(tput sc)
[[ -z "$restore" ]] && restore=$(tput cuu 4)
[[ -z "$restore" ]] && restore=$(tput cuu1; tput cuu1; tput cuu1; tput cuu1)
```

which is still a little crude in the way the number of lines is embedded in the expressions.  But then you could just execute `$restore` at the end of the loop.

Something similar could be done with the check for `el` in the terminal.

Given that this is bash, the `echo "line1"`, etc., should really be a function (which would eliminate the redundant `tput el` calls).

All of these capabilities are likely to be supported with terminals that OP is likely to encounter.  The save/restore cursor controls are a weak point, since there are two main variants:

- `DECSC`/`DECRC` (supported by xterm - see [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Controls-beginning-with-ESC)):

  ```
  ESC 7     Save Cursor (DECSC).
  ESC 8     Restore Cursor (DECRC).
  ```
- ANSI.SYS (also supported by xterm, but not by all "xterm emulators"):

  ```
  CSI s     Save cursor (ANSI.SYS), available only when DECLRMM is disabled.
  CSI u     Restore cursor (ANSI.SYS).
  ```

Other useful sources of information:

- [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)
- [console_codes(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)

The question, by the way, is mis-titled, since the example given (and so far none of the answers) uses *scrolling*.  One could (again referring to terminfo, and limiting oneself to VT100-like terminals such as xterm) use scrolling regions.  The place to start would be here (from the terminfo manual page):

```
   change_scroll_region          csr        cs        change region to      
                                                      line #1 to line #2    
                                                      (P)
```

Comment: thomas - re my edit: one answer in which i used a lot of nested codeblocks is [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212970/52934). i only mention it because i used to resort to those back-quoted strings in (un)?ordered lists here, too, until i learned the other way was possible. you just need to factor the indentation.