# Trouble installing rEFInd boot manager

Tags: uefi, boot-loader, refind

I have downloaded the [rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) boot manager, and want to figure out how to install it by script. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/REFInd) says I simply run the script:

```
$ sudo refind-install
```

However, upon execution I get back the error

```
sudo: refind-install: command not found
```

Where can I find this command and run the script accordingly?

Comment: you downloaded it from sourceforge or you installed it with `pacman`? if you got it from sourceforge you'll be looking for `../refind_unzipped_dir/install.sh`. see *part of* [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212970/52934). or, and better yet, see [Rod's own instructions](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html).

Comment: I downloaded it from the Arch Linux package center. And the mirror was flagged out of date.

Comment: you downloaded the `.tar.xz` at the *download from mirror* link [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/refind-efi/)? if so, you'll still need to install it. `pacman -U ./refind*xz`. that's the `pacman` package file, though. i'm pretty sure it's got all you need within, and after running it your `refind-install` should work as you need, but it seems to me that if you're an arch linux user you would have just `pacman -S refind-efi` in the first place. so you might want to look again at the rodsbooks link above, or, at the least, at some `pacman` arch wiki articles.