# grub error: you need to load kernel first

Tags: debian, system-installation, grub2, debian-installer

I'm installing Debian 9 on an HP ProLiant DL180. When I boot from a USB drive, it opens grub2 and when I type `boot` it gives an error : `you need to load kernel first`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From `grub-rescue` type `set` then hit the  <kbd>Tab</kbd> , it will help you to set the first parameters , e,g.:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
insmod normal
normal
```

> you need to load kernel first

To load the kernel forward with the following commands:

```
insmod linux
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Change `/dev/sda2` with your root partition , change `gpt2` with `msdos` if you don't have a GUID partition table.

To correctly set your boot parameters, see [Ubuntu documentation : search and set](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#Search_.26_Set)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: i got this "unknown filesystem" after running `linux /vmlinux root=/dev/sda2`

Comment: @AlexanderMills I have added a link to correctly set the root partition.

Comment: From the default menuentry in `set pager=1; cat (hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, I saw "`linux /vmlinuz-6.1.0-2-rt-amd64 root=UUID=4ed3962d-ea68-4e6a-903d-a1fef9df2817 ro nosmt`" and "`linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=4ed3962d-ea68-4e6a-903d-a1fef9df2817 ro nosmt`" was what worked for me.

Comment: I didn't set `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true` in my GRUB configuration, so it was using UUIDs to refer to filesystems instead of devices like `/dev/sda2`.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, secure boot was on. I just turned it off and it worked for me.
Try to turn secure boot off

Command to check secure boot status

```
mokutil --sb-state
```

Comment: After installing twice, I found that this was the only one helped...Superb thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a kernel file and usually an initrd file and the kernel command line, too, before you can run the `boot` command (see the Grub documentation).

Normal boot media offer a menu from which you can select and entry. A Grub command line is not for you. Either you are using your Grub wrongly or you should use a different boot medium.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same error on a workstation with bootable partitions on both of two fixed disks (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`); couldn't find a solution here or elsewhere. Describing my own fix here, as found by trial and error:

Upon

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-install /dev/sda
```

the GRUB boot menu showed all operating systems installed in various partitions on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` (Windows, SuSE 15.3 and earlier).  Booting entries from `/dev/sda` worked fine, choosing one from `/dev/sdb` gave the error

> you need to load the kernel first...

`/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` showed the two hard disks as "`hd0`" and "`hd1`".  <kbd>F2</kbd> at startup shows these entries in BIOS (old machine, no EFI):

```
Main:

   SATA Port 0  [ST3500413AS]-(S0)]
   SATA Port 1  [Optiarc DVD RW-(S1)]
   SATA Port 2  None
   SATA Port 3  [ST3500413AS]-(S3)]
   SATA Port 4  None
   SATA Port 5  None

Boot -> Boot priority order:

    1:      SATA CD: Optiarc DVD RW-(S1)
    2:      Bootable Add-in Cards
    3:      SATA 0:  ST3500413AS-(S0)
    4:      SATA 3:  ST3500413AS-(S3)
```

I'm wondering whether the empty SATA Port 2 is causing the problem?

My fix has been to manually edit `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` (egad, explicitly discouraged in file header!) and to replace all instances of "`hd1`" by "`hd2`". Then again:

grub2-install /dev/sda

---

GRUB's boot menu is the same as before, but booting works for all entries now, including those on `/dev/sdb`.