# Ubuntu 19.10 boots into GRUB and I have to manually load the kernel. How do I have it load automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, grub2, upgrade

Earlier today I was upgrading my computer from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. The update temporarily broke my computer, booting into GRUB safe mode. With the accepted answer from [grub error: you need to load kernel first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first][1]) I was able to load the kernel, specifically the following snippet:

`insmod linux
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd /initrd.img
boot`

That allowed me to load into my OS, and I used the solution proposed in [Login loop on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/1184177) to help me finish updating. Now, my computer works fine, but I still need to input the code that to which I referred earlier. How can I have it so that it will automatically boot into my Ubuntu kernel?

EDIT: Thankfully solved by the comments below.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-grub` to update your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Comment: I'm getting `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of 'dev/sda2'.` right now.

Comment: That sounds really broken. Can you try a reinstall with `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (assuming `/dev/sda` is the target drive) followed by `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Would you mind to write a short [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) to your question?
Comments can be deleted and are not a reliable source. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using [Freddy's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/332764/freddy) comments, specifically `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and then `sudo update-grub`.