# Cannot start Ubuntu 11.10: Kernel too old

Tags: grub2

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 20.04.I cannot start Ubuntu 11.10 from GRUB. I get the messages:

```
error: kernel too old error: you need to load the kernel first
```

What can I do?

Comment: Add the kernels that appear and the kernel that you are selecting for Ubuntu 11.10 to your question. I'm sure you know but Ubuntu 11 has been EOL for many years.

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first

Comment: Hello, I followed the instructions and some other similar ones that I found but without luck. I gave up because it was indeed a quite old Linux and it this issue had consumed a lot of time.