# failure reading sector 0x465aa00 from 'hd0'

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, grub2, ls

Currently in grub2 ( trying to solve a boot problem )  , coming from this post
[grub error: you need to load kernel first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418401)
However whenever I am tying to set the Linux kernel using this command
`linux (hd0,gpt1)/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.-37-generic`

I am getting

`error: failure reading sector 0x465aa00 from 'hd0'`

It cannot be a hard drive problem because i can clearly use `ls -la (hd0,gpt1)/` or any such `ls` commands and can see the contents ( i wouldn't have known which vmlinuz to take without seeing the contents of boot )

So if anyone can help me on this it would be really appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can `ls -la` doesn't mean your disk is errors-free. Please boot from a live CD and run these commands:

1. This is the most basic one: once it finishes you can be sure your disk is readable and working:

   ```
   cat /dev/sda > /dev/null
   echo $?
   dmesg | tail
   ```

   You must get 0 as a result and `dmesg` output should contain no errors as well.
2. Then just in case:

   ```
   e2fsck -f -v -C 0 -t /dev/sdaX
   ```

   Where `sdaX` is your Linux partition. Please run this command for each partition.
3. Lastly I'd run

   ```
   smartctl -t long /dev/sda
   ```

   This command will take a lot of time to complete (a lot less for SSD). After it finishes, run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` to check for any S.M.A.R.T. errors.

Comment: The first command that you wrote in three lines , should I write all of it in one line and execute ? Also just by itself the first line was taking a while

Comment: It was taking a bit of time so i decided to check the disks and here is the SMART data page https://ibb.co/zZYgs7y also this is the normal page https://ibb.co/k5gb30P

Comment: SMART output looks fine. The `cat /dev/sda > /dev/null` command may take up to 3 hours to complete.

Comment: actually i am running using bootable usb , using it for that much time , wont it harm the usb ? Also does that command run a smart long test ? because i was just checking and the smart long test time is about 180 mins. also i did a smart short test  and its ongoing (but its not going past 90% even though it should take 1 min to finish )

Comment: all tests , short long or conveyance are not going beyond 90% remaining ? https://ibb.co/GQFF5ps

Comment: also , I didnt check this before but some of the parts are "OFFLINE" in the SMART analysis gui , https://ibb.co/Y07xjSs

Comment: `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` test takes as long as `cat /dev/sda > /dev/null` to complete. ONLINE and OFFLINE indicate when these attributes get updated. Simply ignore this column.