# Ubuntu 20.04 stucked at grub-rescue

Tags: ubuntu, grub, boot-loader

When I started the system, computer automatically opened `grub-rescue`.

I use command: `ls`:
`(proc) (hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)`

System installed on `(hd1,gpt1)` and it contains:
`(hd1,gpt1)/efi` -> `efi/ubuntu/` `efi/boot`

If I try to `boot`, there is a error: `you need to load the kernel first.`

I can't find any file, which call `vmlinuz` or `initrd.img`, so how can I restore my system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grub error: you need to load kernel first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first)