# Stuck on boot screen, saying you need to load the kernel first

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro

There were a lot of octopi upgrad / updates pending. I began updating them. Suddenly after some time, I got the screen saying:

"The screen locker is broken and unlocking is not possible anymore. In order to unlock switch to a virtual terminal(e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2), log in and execute the command.

`loginctl unlock-session 2`

Afterwards switch back to the running session (Ctrl+Alt+F1). "

I tried to do what it says. But there seems to be an error every time saying login unsuccessful despite putting correct password. I had no option ( At least I thought so) other than force shutdown.

I switched on and got an error :

"error: file '/boot/vmlinuz-4.19-x86_64' not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
Press any key to continue..."

I tried solution like disable secure boot, to my surprise it was already disabled.

Please suggest some solution.

Laptop: HP

The boot screen has 4 options :

1. Manjaro linux
2. Advanced options for Manjaro linux (4 kernels inside)
3. Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)
4. Memory tester (memtest86+)

I am quite new to linux. Almost a newbie, as you might have realised by now.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). While it may be extra work for _you_ to transcribe to text, most of the others here will _not_ do the extra work when they are trying to help you--unless you are willing to pay them for their work.

Comment: As for your problem... You stated that this occurred while doing updates. My guess would be that one of the updates was in the process of updating your boot system / operating system, and your force restart caused that to become corrupt. You will need to learn about recuse and recovery (if you are lucky--if not, you will need to reinstall everything from scratch. And learn to disable the screen saver/blanker/locker when you know something will take awhile to complete: It probably tried to update your screen locker as well, while it was active...).

Comment: I did the changes as you suggested. I shifted temporarily to windows for a while. I learned the lesson.

Comment: (Correcting the typo in my comment: "recuse" -> "rescue". And an additional note: Look at the site's help section (the "help" link near the editor) for help on formatting text when you need to demonstrate text or code blocks, etc. It helps make things more clear.) Did you see the Answer someone posted and try that or other rescue / recovery methods?

Comment: I will surely check out how to format. 
Going to try the provided solution on weekend. I will accept that solution for now, as it seems the right answer. I will post the update later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may have been asked before. Here is a link to the post hopefully it is useful. [grub error: you need to load kernel first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first).

Rather simple solution too. It involves using `grub-rescue`, insert module `insmod` to load the kernel. Hope this is helpful.